# UITextView moves up when keyboard appears

Tags: ios7, uitextview

I have a uitextview inserted programmatically in a toolbar anchored to the bottom of the view.  Whenever the keyboard appears the textview tracks above the keyboard and removes itself from the toolbar, to which it never returns but instead continues to track above the keyboard when the keyboard is called from other textviews. The textview is not set as an input accessory view and it is not called as the first responder in any functions. Has anyone else seen this problem and does anyone have a solution? Please advise, and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had named my textView inputAccessoryView for legacy reasons. Changing the name solved the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Why did your original name cause a problem, what did you change it to, and why did changing it solve the problem?